# Remove Camera Raw (CR2) preview on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update, camera-raw

Yesterday my Windows 8.1 installed about 60 updates. One effect is that CR2 files from my Canon SLR suddenly have a thumbnail preview and are displayed when browsing a folder with the Windows Photo Viewer.

This feature messes with my workflow and I'd like to disable it. Is that possible somehow?

Comment: The CR2 thumbnails can be easily disabled .. Use regedit and go to
\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.cr2\ShellEx and delete the {xyz-whatever-here-is} key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the browsing problem, I decided to switch to XnView and use the following trick: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5957/simple-app-for-viewing-jpg-and-then-deleting-jpgraw-files-simultaneously/43800#43800

You don't need to implement simultaneous delete mentioned there and can also just enable skipping cr2 files, but I found it a nice extra.

And to remove the preview, I extended vembutech's advice: I had to search for the registry key "Microsoft Camera Codec Pack" as well (found it twice) and remove CR2 from the list of FileExtensions there.

Answer (score 0):

Switch the view of the folder/drive that contains those CR2 files that you speak of. Switching to list or detail will eliminate those pesky thumbnails.

Comment: This does not address the second issue (browsing with the Photo Viewer). And in addition, I'd like to view thumbnails, but only once for each image (and not twice as you get when both jpg and cr2 of a file are in the same folder).